# 2 Manifests with 2 application tags

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I have a project with a product flavor that uses a different activity than the main code. I had to define that new activity in a second Manifest file, but I still want to use the original main Manifest as well. But with 2 Manifests with 2 
application tags, I get 2 instances of the app installed on the device. Is there a way I can make this work, or will I just have to copy/paste the whole original Manifest and take out the link to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor to an Android library, where all common stuff is located inclusively the manifest. And an app that includes this library as dependency with its own manifest. When building the app the manifest merger should pick up the manifest from the library and merge it with the manifest of the app.

The library could also implement both flavors.